# What data or which data?

Tags: which-what

I want to ask, what/which data different model combinations are using, so do I have to say:

```
Which data is used by the model combinations?
```

or:

```
What data is used by the model combinations?
```

Comment: Both are correct. It is worth noting that some consider *data* a mass noun taking a singular verb, *is*, but some consider it plural and would urge you to use *are*.

Answer (score 7):

`Which` generally suggests a set of possible options, but `what`, on the other hand, allows for arbitrary selection. Additionally, your current consideration of `data` as singular is fine; however, you will need to pair it with a quantifier, as in `data-set`, if you intend to opt for the "choice from possible options mode".

Hence I suggest one of the following.

```
Which data-set is used by the model combinations?
What data are used by the model combinations?
```

The former asks which of a few choices in data-providers are being used, the latter asks what data-points, chosen from any in existence, are being utilized.

Again, the reason for the first sentence being singular and the second plural was to match the idea of *prior defined choices* vs. *arbitrary sample*. [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/data) describes this distinction as between a plural noun and a singular mass noun.

Comment: +1 I wondered if I was over-analyzing this but you nailed it.  You may wish to include a [reference](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/data) though.